# Center elements inside two div vertically

Tags: css

How can I center these four buttons inside their own div vertically and horizontally?

Update: No Flexbox please. I do not have that luxury.

```css
#outer {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: black;
  display: table-cell;
}

#innerOne {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#innerOne {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="innerOne">
    <button>One</button>
    <button>Two</button>
  </div>
  <div id="innerTwo">
    <button>Three</button>
    <button>Four</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want "one", "two" to be centered inside the blue div vertically and horizontally. The same for "three" and "four" in the black div.

I have tried many different options by setting their display to table and table-cell without the desired effect I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for a single line, you could use a `line-height` equal to the box's `height` to `vertical align` at the center the inline content.

and `text-align` for the horizontal part

```css
#outer {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: black;
  /*display: table-cell;useless here i believe*/
  text-align:center;
}


#innerOne,
#innerTwo {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  line-height:100px;
  background-color: blue;
}
#innerOne {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="innerOne">
    <button>One</button>
    <button>Two</button>
  </div>
  <div id="innerTwo">
    <button>Three</button>
    <button>Four</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the buttons are inline blocks you can center them vertically using a pseudo-element. The pseudo element has the height of the container (`.inner`), and is vertically aligned, and all inline blocks with less height, will be centered to it. 
To center them horizontally set `text-align: center` on the container (`.inner`).

```css
#outer {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: black;
}

.inner {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

.inner::before {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  content: '';
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#innerOne {
  background-color: red;
}

#innerTwo {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="innerOne" class="inner">
    <button>One</button>
    <button>Two</button>
  </div>
  <div id="innerTwo" class="inner">
    <button>Three</button>
    <button>Four</button>
  </div>
</div>
```